# Printing is delayed in 12.10

Tags: printing, brother

I use Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop (Intel CORE 2 DUO @ 2.0 GHz, 2 GB RAM) with a network printer (Brother MFC-8710DW) and the printing is very delayed. I am using the newest version of the cupswrapper driver from the Brother Solutions Center. After I hit print, a little printer icon pops up in the top right corner next to the battery icon, wireless icon, volume, etc.... and it just hangs there. The printing is delayed anywhere from thirty seconds to one minute. While this isn't too much of a problem, it can be if I have to print something last minute before running out the door to get to school on time. Is this caused by some sort of error? If so, how can I fix this error? Is it caused by something else? How do I get my printing to be faster?

Thank for your help in advance.

I was asked to include the logs. This is /var/log/cups/access_log:

```
localhost - smithfamily [31/Oct/2012:16:23:57 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-    Subscription successful-ok
localhost - smithfamily [31/Oct/2012:16:37:56 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-    Subscription successful-ok
localhost - smithfamily [31/Oct/2012:17:17:10 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 186 Renew-    Subscription client-error-not-found
localhost - smithfamily [31/Oct/2012:17:17:10 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 176 Create-    Printer-Subscription successful-ok
```

/var/log/cups/page_log was empty when I checked

/var/log/cups/error_log:

```
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'Brother-MFC-7820N-Gray..' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-Brother-MFC-7820N' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215-Gray..' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215-RGB..' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-HP_Color_LaserJet_CP1215' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateProfile failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:profile id 'MFC-8710DW-Gray..' already exists
W [31/Oct/2012:16:21:44 -0700] CreateDevice failed: org.freedesktop.ColorManager.AlreadyExists:device id 'cups-MFC-8710DW' already exists
```

There were some other files in this directory, but they were .gz files, so I was unsure of whether I should include them. The files were:

access_log.1.gz

access_log.2.gz

access_log.3.gz

error_log.1.gz

error_log.2.gz

error_log.3.gz

Should I include these as well in order to solve the problem (if there is one)?

Comment: Could you share your logs? /var/log/cups/access_log /var/log/cups/error_log etc

Comment: I would like to suggest check Cups configuration (print server) and printer settings.

Comment: @K.KPatel I'm sorry, I don't know how to do that or what those settings would be. Could you elaborate? Thanks!

Comment: Printer settings depends on your printer. Rwead manul given by its manufecturer with it. The CUPS web interface is available on your machine at the following URL:

    http://localhost:631

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By installing the Generic driver rather than the one from Brother, this issue seems to have been solved for me.